# Can't resolve @material-ui/core by using Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, compiler-errors, dependencies

I am receiving: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core'. Here, I have used Container, AppBar, Typography, Grow, Grid from the dependency. My dependency version in package.json file is ^4.11.2. Please help me.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYwll.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ8cw.png)

I have tried to install material-ui/core by using npm install @material-ui/core --legacy-peer-deps. And tried to update the version of the dependency. But, it doesn't work till now.

Comment: Can you provide the repo link?